# django migrations and git branches while working on multiple features simultaneously

Tags: django, git, django-migrations, git-flow

In **Django**, when working on multiple new features simultaneously, what is the best way to handle database migrations with git?
(as in `python manage.py makemigrations` , and `python manage.py migrate`  which are used to update the database after the `models.py` file has been changed)

I’m in middle of working on feature1, on its own branch.
Now I need to create feature2 and push it to production.

Should I:

1. fork new feature2 branch off of production, create feature2, merge back to prod, migrate.
2. fork new feature2 branch off of production, create feature2, migrate, merge back to prod.

Or some other way?

And when I go back to feature1, what do i do to insure everything will be up to date?

Comment: What do you mean of migrating? Do you change version control, git servers, or framework version?

Comment: in Django whenever changes are made to the models you need to run `makemigrations` in order to update the actual database. Thanks for asking, i edited the question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the first option has to be done otherwise, the final product won't work (at least cannot be guaranteed). IMO the second option should be also done, because it makes `feature2` testable, therefore ready to merge into main.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a **database migration tool** by **command line** in conjunction with git you can take advantage of *up* and *downs* SQL scripts.

Let's say you want to add some changes to your DB, through the migration tool you can define a `namescript1-up.sql` and `namescript1-down.sql` and you can checkout to a specific database version from the command line (after a git checkout).

For example, I use [golang-migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) for my go apps (I think it can be used for any language when used by command line).

Anyway, I would say this is an improper use of a migration tool, which is more suitable to apply the scripts regarding only the schema variations and not regarding ordinary INSERT or UPDATE sql statements.

I would suggest working on a containerized version of your DB, so you can destroy and recreate anything on flight.